# Looping through a drop-down list in Excel and pasting the results in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop-down list and it outputs a Buy/Sell recommendation based on certain calculations. I want to:

1. Iterate through each item in the drop-down list
2. Paste each resulting Buy/Sell recommendation in a new sheet

I found a code on the Internet that I adapted to my use.
 The drop-down is in "Worksheet" (Cell H2). The resulting recommendation is in the same sheet, Cell H3. The results are in the sheet called "Dashboard", starting from Cell B2.

```
Sub Pasting()
Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long




'Which cell has data validation
Set dvCell = Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("H2")
'Determine where validation comes from
Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)




i = 2
'Begin our loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In inputRange
    dvCell = c.Value
    
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(i, "B").Value = Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("H3").Value
    i = i + 1
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True




End Sub
```

The code 'removes' the value in the cell of my drop-down list and as a result the entire output in the 'Dashboard' worksheet populates as 'Speculate'.

Appreciate the help to amend the code or suggest new code. 
Thanks

Comment: It looks like your code works, but you want the original value in H2 to be restored when the process is finished. Just store that value, such as `Dim originalInput As Variant; originalInput = dvCell.Value`, then use that to restore that value at the end of the method.

Comment: As the code is, it is just replacing everything with H3, should it not be replacing everything with `dvCell` ?

Comment: @Davesexcel I replaced `Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("H3").Value` with `dvCell.Value`. Now, I am getting #VALUE error and the cell H2 still goes blank.